# CordovaFileTransfer | How put string from the headers to TargetPath?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have project write with Ionic Framework and AngularJS. 
His task is to download files from the URL, type as http://www.uzhnu.edu.ua/uk/infocentre/get/6500
The problem is that the examples of "how to download the file and give it a name" is only if the path to URL line have his name .

The name of my file does not have this name in url. It is in the headers of http request, here is screen made with [POSTMAN](http://prntscr.com/ash9bc), but how to get it and put in a variable TargetPath, I do not know. Can anyone suggest something?
Here is code of

FileTransferController.js:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaFile, $cordovaDialogs, $window, $ionicLoading,$ionicPopup, $timeout, $cordovaFileTransfer) {

  $scope.id = '6500';

  $scope.downloadFile = function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Download file...'});
    var url = "http://www.uzhnu.edu.ua/uk/infocentre/get/"+$scope.id;
    var filename = $scope.id+".doc";
    alert(filename);
    var targetPath = "/storage/sdcard0/documents/" + filename;
    var trustHosts = true;
    var options = {};
    $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
      .then(function(entry) {
          // Success!
          $ionicLoading.hide();
          console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
          alert('File download: ' + targetPath);
        }, function(error) {
          $ionicLoading.hide();
          // An error occured. Show a message to the user
          alert('Sorry');
          alert(JSON.stringify(error));
          console.log("download error source " + error.source);
          console.log("download error target " + error.target);
          console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
        },
        false,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Disposition": ""
          },
        });
  };
});
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
  .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      }
      if(window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    });
  })
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
  <title></title>

  <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
  <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
  -->
  <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <!-- ng-cordova  -->
  <script src="js/ng-cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ng-cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
  <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <!-- your app's js -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/FileTransferController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">
<ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button class="button-positive" ng-click="downloadFile()">Download File</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. Code work only on real device. And must download all plugins:

ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file

ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer

and in folder "js" add file "ng-cordova.js" and "ng-cordova.min.js". DOwnload they can with:

bower install ngCordova

Comment: Here is example with download file
[Example](http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.in/2015/03/file-upload-download-with-ng-cordova.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES! Finally I did it!If someone will need a code, her ir is:

```
 $scope.downloadFile = function() {
    var url = "http://example.com/page";
    $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Download file...'});
    $http.get(url).
      success(function (data, status, headers) {
        var head = headers('Content-Disposition');
        var filename = head.substr(head.lastIndexOf('=')+1);
        alert(filename);
        var targetPath = "/storage/sdcard0/documents/" + filename;
        var trustHosts = true;
        var options = {};
        $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
          .then(function(entry) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
            alert('File download: ' + targetPath);
          }, function(error) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            console.log('headers: ' + headers('Cache-Control'));
            // An error occured. Show a message to the user
            alert('Sorry');
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
          })
        alert(head1);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
        return(JSON.stringify(head1))
      })
      .error(function (status) {
        alert(status);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
      });
  };
```